# Can anyone help me to get symbolic expression for the following code?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

Using Mathematica I did some manipulation on the function  $\sum _{s=-m}^{m} e^i \lambda ^{-(2-d) s} \left(1-e^{i y \lambda ^s}\right)$.

And got the following output:

(1) when I took $\text{m}$ in the above summation to be from $(-1,1)$ that is I considered the function  $\sum _{s=-1}^1 e^i \lambda ^{-(2-d) s} \left(1-e^{i y \lambda ^s}\right)$, and for this after doing some manipulations i got the following output,

```
-(1/(α Gamma[α])) E^I x^α λ^(-2 - 
  d) (-λ^4 - λ^(2 d) - λ^(
   2 + d) + λ^(2 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)] + λ^4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^2))] + λ^(2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2] + (
   I x λ^(2 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^3 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^2))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(1 + 2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2])/(1 + α))
```

(2) Again I took the same function with  $\text{m}$  from $(-2,2)$ and did the same manipulation as in (1) and got the following output,

```
-(1/(α Gamma[α])) E^I x^α λ^(-2 (2 + 
    d)) (-λ^8 - λ^(4 d) - λ^(
   6 + d) - λ^(4 + 2 d) - λ^(
   2 + 3 d) + λ^(4 + 2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)] + λ^8 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^4))] + λ^(6 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^2))] + λ^(2 + 3 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2] + λ^(4 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^4] + (
   I x λ^(4 + 2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^6 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^4))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(5 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^2))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(3 + 3 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(2 + 4 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^4])/(1 + α))
```

(3) Again I repeated the same manipulation with $\text{m}$  from $(-3,3)$ and the output was,

```
    d)) (-λ^12 - λ^(6 d) - λ^(
   10 + d) - λ^(8 + 2 d) - λ^(6 + 3 d) - λ^(
   4 + 4 d) - λ^(
   2 + 5 d) + λ^(6 + 3 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)] + λ^12 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^6))] + λ^(10 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^4))] + λ^(8 + 2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 1 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^2))] + λ^(4 + 4 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2] + λ^(2 + 5 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^4] + λ^(6 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + α/2, 
      1 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^6] + (
   I x λ^(6 + 3 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/
      4)])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^9 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(x^2/(4 λ^6))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(8 + d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^4))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(7 + 2 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 3/2 + α/2}, -(
      x^2/(4 λ^2))])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(5 + 4 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^2])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(4 + 5 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^4])/(1 + α) + (
   I x λ^(3 + 6 d)
     HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + α/2, 
      3/2 + α/2}, -(1/4) x^2 λ^6])/(1 + α))
```

I need to form a symbolic expression for the output of my manipulation so to obtain it I did the same manipulation three times with different $\text{m}$ to guess the general notation of the output (i.e) when $\text{m}$ is from $-\text{n}$ to $\text{n}$.

But from the above evaluation results I was not able to guess the symbolic expression.. Could anyone please help me to get a symbolic notation for my manipulation..

And I am not sure whether the methodology applied by me in finding a symbolic notation is correct.

This is the code which i used to get the above output

```
Assuming[ Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && Re[α] > 0, 
 Integrate[(x - y)^((α) - 
    1) ((Sum[((Exp[I*1])*(1 - 
         Exp[y *I*(λ)^s] ))/λ^(s*(2 - d)), {s, -1, 
       1}])), {y, 0, x}]/ Gamma[(α)]]
Assuming[ Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && Re[α] > 0, 
 Integrate[(x - y)^((α) - 
    1) ((Sum[((Exp[I*1])*(1 - 
         Exp[y *I*(λ)^s] ))/λ^(s*(2 - d)), {s, -2, 
       2}])), {y, 0, x}]/ Gamma[(α)]]
Assuming[ Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && Re[α] > 0, 
 Integrate[(x - y)^((α) - 
    1) ((Sum[((Exp[I*1])*(1 - 
         Exp[y *I*(λ)^s] ))/λ^(s*(2 - d)), {s, -3, 
       3}])), {y, 0, x}]/ Gamma[(α)]]
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a closed form for this: $\sum _{s=-m}^{m} e^i \lambda ^{-(2-d) s} \left(1-e^{i y \lambda ^s}\right)$ sum?

Comment: I noticed if you do `ExpandAll[E^I \[Lambda] ^(-(2 - d) s) (1 - E^(I y \[Lambda]^s))]` you get two parts. If you `FullSimplify@Sum[...]` both parts you get this, but the sum on the rhs will not simplify: $$\frac{e^i \lambda ^{(-d-2) m} \left(\lambda ^{2 d m+d}-\lambda ^{4 m+2}\right)}{\lambda ^d-\lambda ^2}-\sum
   _{s=-m}^m \lambda ^{d s-2 s} e^{i y \lambda ^s+i}$$